# Adding a file to a Restsharp Post request

Tags: c#, restsharp

I am trying to attach a file to this `RestSharp` post request but the `AddFile` method errors out because it can't find the file which is in the root directory. Am I using it incorrectly?

```cs
var client = new RestClient(ENDPOINT);
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

...adding authorization to request

string path = @"C:\";
request.AddFile("file.json", path);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
string result = response.StatusDescription;
```

Answer (score 1):

First Parameter of AddFile is not basically the name of the file but it represents the name of the parameter to be used for the request

Official description for AddFile name parameter is
**The Parameter name to use in the request**

```
string path = @"C:\file.json";
request.AddFile("nameoftheParamter", path);
```

Comment: So how do you send a file?